# How to specify order for useEffect() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a doubt about React. I have two functions in

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './transactions.css'

function TransactionHistory () {
  const [last_account_id, setAccountId] = useState();
  const http_request = async url => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return [true, response];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return [false, null];
    }
  }

  const get_transactions = async () => {
    let transactions_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let transactions = http_request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions');
      resolve(transactions);
    });
    let transactions_response = await transactions_promise;
  }

  const get_account_details = async () => {
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/' + last_account_id;
    let account_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let account = http_request(url)
      resolve(account)
    })
    let account_response = await account_promise
  }

  const run_apis = async () => {
    await get_transactions();
    await get_account_details();
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    run_apis()
  }, [last_account_id])
  return ()
}

export default TransactionHistory
```

I am getting a bad request initially from get_account_details() and failing my test cases. But it works after. The useState last_account_id is not defined initially and that is causing the bad request.

Please help me figure out a solution.

Comment: does funct1 return a promise? you could do funct1().then(()=> funct2()) if that's the case

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This didn't work. The bad request call from funct2() goes before funct1() is ran.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this question comes from a comment on another answer, quoted here:

> Bad request error comes from funct2() due to a useState not defined in funct1()

Then you are triggering `funct2` in response to the wrong thing. If you need it to run when a state is defined, then you should make it run in response to that state changing by putting it in its own effect hook.

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    func1();
}, []); // Note the addition of the dependency array so that this only runs when the component is initially mounted

useEffect(() => {
    if (someState === null) return; // Don't run funct2 if the state hasn't been set yet
    funct2();
}, [someState]); // Note that we run this function whenever the state is changed
```

---

Alternatively, you could have `funct1` return the value (possibly via an `await`ed promise), then pass that value to `funct2` and then read the value from the arguments instead of the state (because the old value of the state would have been closed over at that point).

Answer (score -1):

You can wait for the function to finish with await

```js
const executeFns = async () => {
  await funct1();
  await funct2();
};

// Then in your effect you can call your "executeFns"
useEffect(() => {
  executeFns();
}, []);
```

Comment: What makes you think that `funct1` return a promises? Where does the "bad request" come from?

Comment: If they're getting a bad request, that means they are doing some async operation, however it was not specified

Comment: Bad request error comes from funct2() due to a useState not defined in funct1()

Comment: A bad request error means they are **probably** doing something with Ajax, but it is quite a leap from there to `funct1` returning a promise and more of a leap to think that waiting for that promise will stop the request being bad.

Comment: We need more info to understand the problem. However, it's quite common that the error is because of the poor management of async operations, that why this is an aswer to the little information we have

Comment: @MártinAlcalá I have already tried what you suggested but the bad request from funct2 goes first.